# Is there a line between philosophy which problems are solvable by "pure thought" and which aren't?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, metaphilosophy, introduction-to-philosophy

It seems to me like a lot of arguments in philosophy are aided by insights of science, math, etc. For example, the [relation between evolution and morals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/morality-biology/) or [Kant and geometry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemology-geometry/) (and later non-Euclidian geometry was shown to be more relevant via Einstein). This seems to indicate that the enterprise of philosophy is one that cannot be solved through pure logic alone.

While I appreciate that perhaps we are doing the best we can have, philosophers called this out? Has there been any attempt to draw a line between philosophy which problems are solvable by "pure thought" and which aren't? And what criteria are used for this?

Comment: Maybe just check the structure at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_philosophy

Comment: @MoreAnonymous  "*pure logic alone*" No conclusion can be decided only using pure logic. You cannot reason logically without assuming some premises, premises which can only be motivated by what the thinker believes about the world. So there is no such a thing as "*pure thought*".

Comment: @Speakpigeon, your claim is false. Are you saying some things can't be reasoned alone? Sciences & Mathematics seems to indicate there must be some sort of assumption. Deductive reasoning does not require assumptions. If we are given a definition per se we can reason from the definition alone to resolve a specific problem. That is we face a problem & we are given a definition we can come to an absolute conclusion.  Show me why we can't.  You must define TRUTH if you are going to use the how do you know x is true line on me here. There are different kinds of truth. You must state the context.

Comment: The movement you need to look up is called RATIONALISM. You also have to be aware that now days philosophy is not like the good old days of Plato or Aristotle. Now a days a lot of philosophy is mixed with other subject areas so the philosophers can make a living. Philosophy of Mind is an example of that. You ought to notice the differences between philosophy in the past & now. Now we include many emotional topics & considerations that Aristotle wouldn't do. Perhaps the world doesn't like objective truths. Socrates died as well as others for objective knowledge. Masses don't like it.

Comment: @Logikal "*your claim is false*" Prove it is false. 2. "*Are you saying some things can't be reasoned alone?*" Sorry, I don't understand. 3. "*Sciences & Mathematics seems to indicate there must be some sort of assumption.*" Exactly. Any reasoning about something requires some relevant assumption about it. A does not imply B. 4. "*If we are given a definition per se we can reason from the definition alone to resolve a specific problem.*" Sure, but the definition has to be relevant to the problem and the conclusion will depend on the specific relevance of the definition. What's your point?

Comment: @Logikal "*That is we face a problem & we are given a definition we can come to an absolute conclusion.*" In some cases, sure, but not necessarily. Problem: A implies B. Definition: C and D equivalent to E. Can you prove A implies B from C and D equivalent to E? No. - 2. "*Show me why we can't*" I just did. - 3. "*You must define TRUTH*" Of course not. We all know what is truth.

Comment: @speakpigeon,  we don't know what truth is the way you are defining it. Are you referring to contingent truths or necessary truths? You are not clear. To prove a implies b doesn't require an assumption necessarily. There happen to be neccessary truths. If I start with a neccessary truth no assumptions are needed. Triangles must have exactly 3 sides is necessary. Object K has three sides. Therefore object k is a triangle.  Math requires an assumption not philosophy. You have not shown why we can't reason from zero assumptions. There are no false instances for neccessary truths.

Comment: @Logikal "*Triangles must have exactly 3 sides is necessary. Object K has three sides. Therefore object k is a triangle*" You have two premises here. Premises are assumptions. There's a reason we say that a conclusion follows from.

Comment: @speak pigeon, can you prove premises are assumptions or are you using a Mathematical logic text definition? Seems like you are because Aristotelian logic doesn't use assumptions whatsoever. An objective truth is not an assumption either. So you have terminology issues here: truth being one of them because you don't want to vote your context and your definition of so called LOGIC is purely from math while Aristotelian logic predates your Mathematical logic. A conclusion follows from the premises is because the premises are related in a way where true premises necessitates a true conclusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136578/discussion-between-speakpigeon-and-logikal).

Comment: @speakpigeon, I cannot use chat unfortunately.

Comment: @speakpigeon, you are strictly using definitions from only Mathematical logic which does not translate into the real world as you think. The whole idea about an ASSUMPTION is that it is language used when ou are not certain of x. It is not an ass6to say all women are human being is it? Why is it an assumption to say all triangles must have exactly three sides? You know the claim cannot be false. Mathematics & science use assumptions to avoid having accountability for making a statement that runs out false.

Comment: @Logikal 1. "can you prove premises are assumptions" This is what premises are. Premises are sentences you assume true, i.e., assumptions. - 2. "Aristotelian logic doesn't use assumptions" It does. Premises are assumptions. 3. "An objective truth is not an assumption either" An objective truth is claim about the real world you assume true, i.e., an assumption. 4. "related in a way where true premises necessitates a true conclusion" Premises need not be true for the conclusion to follow from them. Premises are assumed true. - 5. "Mathematical logic" Really?! Mathematical logic is crap.

Comment: @Logikal 1. "It is not an ass6to say all women are human being is it?" Of course it is. All assertions about the real world are assumptions. - 2. "Why is it an assumption to say all triangles must have exactly three sides?  You know the claim cannot be false" It cannot be false once you assume it is true. This is how assumptions are used for.

Comment: @speakpigeon exactly what source or sources are you getting your information from?   Those sources are Mathematical logic texts. I don't know how you will deny this specifically. Show me and example where Aristotelian logic uses assumptions. What text does Aristotle use the term assumption? In math premises are said to be assumed. In epistemology premises are NOT forced assumptions either. Propositions are true or false objectively by definition. Because you are unaware of a proposition is no excuse to call it an assumption & everyone must agree with you. Assuming means You are not aware. yes?

Comment: @Logical Sorry, I don't understand your comments. That premises are assumptions is notorious and this is obviously how Aristotle thought of them. The term "premise" is just the technical word for assumption used in the context of syllogisms. I'm not going to explain Aristotle to you.  You just need to read the first page of Prior Analytics. Conversation terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

Well, if you take for "pure thought" the heavily [*a priori*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori) notions of [rationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism), then, many professional philosophers believe that [empiricism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empiricism) and *a posteriori* thinking play an important role in a sensible philosophical worldview. As such, they openly embrace science, and do not see a crisp line of division between philosophy and scientific fact. In fact, many famous 20th century philosophers have some relationship with what is termed a [natural epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalized_epistemology), and some very sophisticated philosophers have argued there is no line between the two at all.

### Long Answer

It should be noted that "[thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought)" is a word with some ambiguity in philosophy, and is a term that is somewhat explored in the [philosophy of mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mind). But, I suspect what you're angling for is the notion that [metaphysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics) without regard for real life experience and a bit of experimentation might be an exercise more in vocabulary and hubris than in genuine model building of reality, whatever that might be. A phrase like "grand and sweeping metaphysical framework" describes certain philosophical products of thinkers like Aristotle, Aquinas, Spinoza, Kant, and others to describe with completeness everything known. Such efforts find themselves championed by some and decried by others. A good example of the latter is the [logical positivists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_positivism) who almost 90 years ago made a concerted effort to eliminate metaphysics by declaring it meaningless. Surprise, they failed.

Philosophies and philosophers whose methods lie heavily on introspection might be characterized as Cartesian, named after the somewhat infamous Rene Descartes. His views on [mind-body duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism) still animate a lot of discussion about philosophy and thought, and Daniel Dennett coined the term [Cartesian theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_theater) to push back against certain views. One view that is generally met with skepticism today is the idea that just because you think, and think you are, you can be certain of everything else. ["Cogito ergo sum"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito,_ergo_sum) is probably as contested as it is famous.<sup>1</sup> Another conception of thought termed the [analytic-synthetic distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%E2%80%93synthetic_distinction) has also met with criticism by philosophical giants such as Quine, who attacked the idea in his [*Two Dogmas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Dogmas_of_Empiricism).

> Is there a line between philosophy which problems are solvable by "pure thought" and which aren't?

Modern philosophers who have examined the question about distinctions in knowledge and problems that are either *a priori* or *a posteriori*, either rational or empirical, either synthetic or analytical have generally converged on a simple idea. There is no clear division between one and the other, a notion related to the [sorites paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox), which suggests that nice, convenient, crisp categories are artificial linguistic artifacts, and that definitions and reasoning might be [fuzzy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) or [prototypical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_theory) instead of being swept into tidy sets defined by simple [intensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intension). So it's fair to say that a somewhat popular view of philosophy, that its a bunch of people "[navel gazing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navel_gazing)" engaged in "pure thought" is a misconception. Daniel Dennett certainly knows more about science than Bill Nye knows about philosophy.<sup>2</sup>

---

**1** - My intent here is to caricature Descartes obviously historical brilliance. Certainly he is one of the most influential Western philosophers by consensus. That his views on the pineal gland, the consciousness of animals, and his overestimation of the strengths of logic have not aged well do not undermine his obvious genius. He certainly didn't have access to empirical methods of epistemology that have laid bare the defeasibility of reason.

**2** - My intent here is to goad shallow thinkers who think that science has somehow replaced or made irrelevant philosophy. The advancement of the methodologies of sciences is indebted to philosophy of science, even long before such a term was used. [Bill Nye has since conceded his original views on philosophy were superficial (Quartz)](https://qz.com/960303/bill-nye-on-philosophy-the-science-guy-says-he-has-changed-his-mind/).

Comment: @J D, can you explain in what sense Bill Nye needs philosophy in order to further his program/accomplish his goals? Or is your point that Nye has himself accused philosophers of being navel-gazers? I am confused by the reference. -NN

Comment: @JD "*Philosophies and philosophers whose methods lie heavily on introspection (...) "Cogito ergo sum" is probably as contested as it is famous.*" Descartes never argued as you suggest here that "*just because you think, and think you are, you can be certain of everything else*". In fact, he is famous for arguing very nearly the opposite.

Comment: @Speakpigeon I thought "I think therefore I am" was a worst case scenario where one argues if I cannot trust my 5 senses what can I know. The answer Descartes reached was "I think therefore I am." Is this the correct interpretation? (if not where can I read his version)

Comment: @nielsnielsen That's simple. Bill Nye, a mechanical engineer by trade, relies on 500 years of philosophy to lay claim to the irrefutable victories of science. I reject the supernatural and am a defender of scientism. But ignoring the lineage of science in natural philosophy and the continuation of the philosophy of science to clarify issues like the demarcation problem would set back science to the Ancient Greeks; and that would be a dark age. Logical positivists demonstrated with zeal the indispensability of philosophy, and through their own philosophy, offered DN as a model of explanation.

Comment: @Speakpigeon I am lampooning the excesses of rationalism with metonymy. It's a glib summation, and a tacit tip o' the hat to navel-gazing as a weapon of critique in those who are oblivious or dismissive of empirical routes to knowledge. I certainly don't intend and have no capacity to unseat Descartes philosophical contributions.

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Yes, this is about right, but the Cogito is only about the existence of the mind, i.e., the "thinking thing", it doesn't say anything about the material world supposedly outside, so it is no solution to the failure of our senses to deliver knowledge about the material world. The Cogito is an epistemological dead end, but it's merit is to tell us exactly what is knowledge, and by contrast to relegate our ideas about the material world to mere beliefs. This explains that so many philosophers ridicule themselves trying to dismiss the Cogito using fallacious criticisms.

Comment: @JD Whatever you are trying to say, your piece is fallacious. It suggests something which is totally false.

Comment: @JD "*[Descartes's] overestimation of the strengths of logic*" You sure? Descartes played a major role in Europe to convince other philosophers of the time that logic was barren and impotent. He even tried to remove any suggestion that the Cogito was a logical inference.

Comment: @JD "*empirical methods of epistemology that have laid bare the defeasibility of reason*" Reason has two components, logic and empirical data, and only empirical data are possibly wrong as far as anybody can tell, which is precisely what Descartes himself demonstrated. So, what exactly are you taking about?

Comment: @Speakerpigeon That's just wrong. Logic is subject to fallacy. But further,  logics are constructed linguistic artifacts that are approximative. ie propositional logic is a simple model.  Today, non-monotonic logics and IBE  fill in the gaps for the impoverished logics of Descartes day. Furthermore,  these developments in logic are conducted on automated systems which allow experimention. Hence, Descartes was unaware of how the defeasibilty of logic undergirds fallibilistic epistemology. His logic like his math were innovations,  but are outdated views of both. Time marches on.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-monotonic_logic?wprov=sfla1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defeasibility_%28linguistics%29?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @HD, PEOPLE are subject errors or the ability to commit fallacies not logic itself. Descartes used analytic propositions to prove his existence. If I do not exist then I would not have a mind. I do have a mind because I am capable of thinking. If I am thinking I cannot be deceived into I do not exist. Only existing things are capable of thought. I think therefore I exist.

Comment: @Logikal I reject the analytic-synthetic divide on the basis that the logic used to arrive at it is erroneous. Thus, you have shown how a logic,  which is a description of thought, fails to meet my standards of modeling. Simply put, your logic itself is erroneous, and any attempts to argue otherwise are absolutist for psychological gain.

Comment: @jd there is no psychological gain here. You sound as if you are being an authoritarian over others. You can't just REJECT concepts because you say so & maintain that you are rational. You need to justify why you agree or disagree with ANYTHING if you are to be rational. An authority pulls rank on people & states I reject this or that because I feel like it. There is no such thing as MY LOGIC. Did you mean to say reasoning? Deductive reasoning has rules & I don't control those rules neither do you. You don't get to pick & choose. The rules are established already.

Comment: @Logikal Wow. I seemed to have touched a nerve. Calm yourself. You would have been better off attempting to rebut Quine's Two Dogmas. Since this conversation isn't productive, I'll just leave you w the thought that you're again wrong. I get to pick and choose whatever logic I want. And deductive logic is useful but quaint. I choose the rules of dialeithism and abduction. Deduction is a logic good for toy problems meant for school children.